# How to derive a pose quaternion from orientation vectors with tf2

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, quaternion, tf2, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to calculate the [pose](http://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/Pose.html) of an object using tf2.

I know the X', Y', Z' vectors defining the orientation of the object - ie. the principle axes of the target frame, expressed in the origin frame. I also know the position of the target frame. How can I calculate the pose / quaternion that rotates the origin frame to the target frame (so that I can publish a geometry_msg/Pose for the object)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/378606/how-to-derive-a-pose-quaternion-from-orientation-vectors-with-tf2/) by [LukeAI](https://answers.ros.org/users/38953/lukeai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 131 on 2021-05-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2021-05-19**:
A quaternion is the orientation  vector, that cannot be "calculated" from the position information, that itself is its own information about what the orientation is relative to the reference frame for the full SE3 pose. You have to know your own orientation.

**Comment by [shonigmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/69938/shonigmann/) on 2021-05-19**:
In case LukeAI meant that he had *vectors* for x', y', and z', as in the principle axes of the target frame, expressed in a reference frame, then the pose quaternion can be determined using standard conversions between rotation matrix notation and quaternion notation. But then position would still be missing... so I agree the question could use a bit more clarity

**Comment by [LukeAI](https://answers.ros.org/users/38953/lukeai/) on 2021-05-20**:
@shonigmann that's exactly what I meant, editing for clarity

**Comment by [shonigmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/69938/shonigmann/) on 2021-05-20**:
glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ok worked this out - the x_vec, y_vec, z_vec form the columns of the rotation matrix so the solution is simply:

```
tf2::Matrix3x3 rot_mat;
tf2::Quaternion q;
rot_mat.setValue(x_vec.x, y_vec.x, z_vec.x,
                 x_vec.y, y_vec.y, z_vec.y,
                 x_vec.z, y_vec.z, z_vec.z);
rot_mat.getRotation(q);
```

---

Originally posted by [LukeAI](https://answers.ros.org/users/38953/lukeai/) with karma: 131 on 2021-05-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2